# Is it possible to swizzle UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints?

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I would like to know if UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints is a selector that I can swizzle. All I know so far is that UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints is a symbol that one can use to place a symbolic breakpoint. But I cannot find this symbol in any public class. Does anyone know where it is located?

Note that I'm looking to do this in unit tests, not in production code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints is a C function, swizzling it requires considerably more work than your typical Objective C method.

The simplest (and what most sources say is the only possible way) to do this is via Substrate's [MSHookFunction](http://www.cydiasubstrate.com/api/c/MSHookFunction/), however that requires a jailbroken phone. If this is a valid option I would recommend using that to simply hook the function.

On a non-jailbroken environment, advanced runtime manipulation is required. For some reason I really enjoy throwing away hours at learning a soon to be dead language.. so here is the full solution! This [link](https://github.com/thomasfinch/CRuntimeFunctionHooker/blob/master/inject.c) was a huge help.

```
#import <dlfcn.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int64_t originalOffset;
int64_t *origFunc;

void swizzled_UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint *offendingConstraint, NSArray *allConstraints) {
    // inject swizzle code here
    NSLog(@"swizzled!");

    // call the original function (if you want!)
    if (origFunc) {
        // replace jump instruction w/ the original memory offset
        *origFunc = originalOffset;
        ((void(*)(NSLayoutConstraint*, NSArray*))origFunc)(offendingConstraint, allConstraints);
    }
}

static inline BOOL swizzleAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints() {

    // get the original function and hold onto it's memory offset
    origFunc = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints");
    if (!origFunc) {
        return NO;
    }
    originalOffset = *origFunc;

    // define the swizzled implementation
    int64_t *swizzledFunc = (int64_t*)&swizzled_UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints;

    // make the memory containing the original funcion writable
    size_t pageSize = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    uintptr_t start = (uintptr_t)origFunc;
    uintptr_t end = start + 1;
    uintptr_t pageStart = start & -pageSize;
    mprotect((void *)pageStart, end - pageStart, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);

    //Calculate the relative offset needed for the jump instruction
    //Since relative jumps are calculated from the address of the next instruction,
    //  5 bytes must be added to the original address (jump instruction is 5 bytes)
    int64_t offset = (int64_t)swizzledFunc - ((int64_t)origFunc + 5 * sizeof(char));

    //Set the first instruction of the original function to be a jump
    //  to the replacement function.
    //E9 is the x86 opcode for an unconditional relative jump
    int64_t instruction = 0xe9 | offset << 8;
    *origFunc = instruction;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Just want to let you know that this looks promising and pretty amazing. I'm going to try it out later tonight and mark it as the answer if it works properly. Thanks so much for putting time into it.

Comment: I think I'm using this incorrectly. I get "Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x49656e69))". It looks like the original function is correctly not being called. I see "__swizzleAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints_block_invoke" on the stack trace when I normally would see "AlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints". However, it looks like there's an issue with either the format of the replacement function, or the memory offset. Did you see an issue like this?

Comment: oops! i only tested this on a 32 bit simulator, not a 64 bit. If you try it out on an iPad 2 sim (32 bit) you should see it work. I will update the code tomorrow with a version that works for both 32/64 bit.

Comment: @EdChin, updated the code to make it work for both 32/64 bit devices. unfortunately it isn't quite as clean as before (requires global variables) but it works!

Comment: I noticed that you switched the arguments NSArray and UIView. Is that the difference between 32 vs 64 bit devices? Where did you get the documentation for the C function signature?

Comment: unfortunately i was unable to find documentation for the C function, so it was done by trial and error. it seems like the param signature may actually be NSLayoutConstraint*, NSArray*, UIView*, NSArray*, but the two NSArray objects are always identical and it doesn't seem like the 4 param is necessary.. the change made it work for both 32/64 was replacing imp_implementationWithBlock with a separate C function.

Comment: Updated code for x86_64 also not working on iPhone 6 Plus simulator with iOS 9.0.
Got "Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x49656e69))".

Comment: @ypresto apparently the function only has 2 input params, not 3. Not sure why it works on old devices, but not new ones... either way, the code has been updated and should work now.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Casey's solution and does work fine, but only on simulator.
ARM processor have Thumb mode, so it is much difficult to swizzle using ARM B instruction than x86 JMP.

UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints is called from below method of UIView. It seems to be defined in delegate of internal engine.

```
- (void)engine:(NSISEngine *)arg1 willBreakConstraint:(id <NSISConstraint>)arg2 dueToMutuallyExclusiveConstraints:(NSArray *)arg3;
```

https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/6a384f6a219be448de8714f263a4c212516d52b6/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIView.h#L1108

https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/3dde29deb7000cfac59d3e5473a71557123f29ea/protocols/NSISEngineDelegate.h#L10

Swizzling ObjC method is much easier than C func.

Define private interface:

```
@interface UIView (UIConstraintBasedLayout_EngineDelegate_PrivateInterface)

- (void)engine:(id /* NSISEngine */)engine willBreakConstraint:(NSLayoutConstraint *)breakConstraint dueToMutuallyExclusiveConstraints:(NSArray<NSLayoutConstraint *> *)mutuallyExclusiveConstraints;

@end
```

Then swizzle objc method:

```
+ (void)swizzleAutoLayoutAlertMethod
{
    Class class = [UIView class];
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, @selector(engine:willBreakConstraint:dueToMutuallyExclusiveConstraints:));
    if (!originalMethod) {
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"This platform does not support Auto Layout or interface has been changed."];
    }
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, @selector(swizzled_engine:willBreakConstraint:dueToMutuallyExclusiveConstraints:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(swizzledMethod, originalMethod);
}
```

NOTE: I created lint library for Auto Layout with this idea, refer https://github.com/ypresto/AutoLayoutLint .

Comment: Do not use method_exchangeImplementations for swizzling: https://blog.newrelic.com/engineering/right-way-to-swizzle/